# There exist a relationship between the properties $i)$ and $ii)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuos function. Consider the properties:

$$i) \liminf_{|x|\to\infty} xf(x) =c>0$$
and
$$ii)\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{e^{a|x|^b}}=0,\quad\forall a>0 \quad (b>0);$$

I am trying to understand if there is a relation between $i)$ and $ii)$, I mean if $i)\implies ii)$ and/or $ii)\implies i)$.

About me there is no relationship between $i)$ and $ii)$ but I can't find counterexamples so far.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We probably need some context here. What makes you propose the question in the first place? Did you see an implication between i) and ii) in, e.g., some article?

Comment: @FShrike no, that's only something I'm curious about. During calculus I class, the lecturer made a proof using these 2 assumptions. When I asked if it was possible to lighten them (in the sense if there is a relation about them so that we can skip one), he said that the answer is "probably no". I am looking for a counterexample (even if his "probably no" was not very convinced).

Comment: It would be good if you provided the proof your lecturer made

Comment: The proof is very long and about me it is not useful here and it is not related to my question. I am only interested in understand if there is a relation (in the sense I described above) between these 2 properties.

Comment: There are trivial counter-examples for ii) implies 1). $f(x)=e^{a|x|^{b}/2}$ is one such. i) implies ii) is also false.

Comment: @geetha290krm could you please provide more details? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample, $(ii)$ does not imply $(i)$:

> Let $f(x)=\ln(1+x^2)$.

Counterexample, $(i)$ does not imply $(ii)$ (there’s a risk this is piecewise continuous since I slightly botched together all the elements I needed, but it works, and the principle stands: someone more experienced than myself in mollifying could probably patch this more smoothly):

> Fix any $b\gt0$. Define $f(x)=e^{\sin(\pi x)x^{b+1}}$ on the interval $[0,1]$. For any $n\in\Bbb N$, put $f(x)$ on the interval $[n,n+1/2]$ as $f(x)=\frac{1}{n}e^{\sin(\pi(x-n))\cdot x^{b+1}}$, and on $[n+1/2,n+1]$ as $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{n+1}e^{\sin(\pi(n+1-x))\cdot x^{b+1}}$, where $g(x)=-\frac{2}{n}x+3+\frac{2}{n}$ on $[n+1/2,n]$. $f$ is continuous and extends similarly to a definition  way to a definition for negative $x$. You find that the limit **inferior** of $x\cdot f(x)$ is $1=c\gt0$ yet the limit $(ii)$ does not exist, since it blows up to infinity near $|x|=n+1/2$ and vanishes near $|x|=n$.

Motivation: for the limit $i)$ to exist, we need to have a sequence of points at which $f$ behaves like $1/x$, yet inbetween the points of this sequence $f$ needs to grow extremely rapidly in order for limit $ii)$ not to exist. $g$ interpolates between the $1/n$ points so as to make the function continuous.

There should be a workable link to the graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lpzw4omkb0) (ignore the output for negative $x$).

Comment: FShrike, thank you for the answer. In the counterexample $i)$ does not imply $ii)$, what you call $f(x)$ is actually $f_n(x)$, right?

Comment: No, I define $f$ on each interval $[n,n+1]$ in a slightly different way. After this process, $f$ is defined on all of $x\ge0$. I leave it to you to use the same technique to define $f$, to have the same properties, on $x\lt0$. @C.Bishop